# google-chrome on PinguyOS 12.04 always crashes when it opens a window to select file

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I'm using PinguyOS, and `lsb_release -a` got this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

It crashes when a saving file window or a selecting file window is opened.

Every time I open a window to select the file I want to upload, or I open a window to select where my bookmarks should be exported, etc. the google-chrome crashes.

The google-chrome was install using the package I downloaded from google web site: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/[1](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)

Is there anybody got the issue like this? Please tell me what should I do to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I do, I had the same exact problem.

Saved a file, crash, restarted chrome, worked.. after a while again.
Same goes to the file browse screen crash.

You won't belive what was the fix.
Uninstall IE9. works like a charm for the last week.
try it :)

Comment: eh... Thank you, I have seen your answer. And then I checked my Pinguy OS, and I found that I didn't install IE9 in wine. It's just nothing in wine. Then I remove wine and reboot, but it's just keep crashing...